# Передача данных между Delphi и PHP. Чем можно зашифровать?

Tags: php, delphi

Взгляд упал на PGP, но т.к. особо с ним не знаком, да и компонентов не нашел для Delphi XE7, подскажите что-нибудь подобное из типа "Шифрование с открытым ключом", может быть потому же PGP какие-нибудь примеры приведете или примеры аналогов. Нужно шифровать большие объемы данных 0-500 мб.

Comment: https чем не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

[тут](http://algolist.manual.ru/defence/well_known/) можно почитать про 
*Криптосистема RSA*
Одна из наиболее сильных криптосистем Применяется как часть PGP Основа стойкости - сложность факторизации Время (де)шифрования O(N3), ключ - O(N).

*Шифр Эль-Гамаля* 
(http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread516163.html)

Классика криптографии Основа стойкости - дискретное логарифмирование Время (де)шифрования O(N3), ключ - O(N).

Существуют еще [эллиптические кривые](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F). Elliptic Curves Encryption

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998885/delphi-asymmetric-encryption

**Ссылки на компоненты** https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Delphi/Cryptography/

PS. эти алгоритмы достаточно медленные. Поэтому я бы каждый файл шифровал случайным паролем при помощи AES, а сам пароль шифровал после этого асимметричным шифром и дописывал его к шифрованному посланию.